# The [easing] tag, mathematical or jQuery?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

I just [ran into this suggested tag-wiki-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/118880).

As it seems, [easing](/questions/tagged/easing) can refer to a mathematical function or to a jQuery plugin. Most of the questions tagged with it seem to be about the plugin.

What to do?

Comment: The mathematical term is the more general and could also apply to WPF and Silverlight code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a [jquery-easing](/questions/tagged/jquery-easing) tag, but it doesn't have a wiki.

Transfer the excerpt to that tag, and retag all [easing](/questions/tagged/easing) questions specifically related to jQuery with [jquery-easing](/questions/tagged/jquery-easing)?

It would be a good idea to add a note in the [easing](/questions/tagged/easing) excerpt to tell jQuery people to use the more specific tag.

---

That being said, I'm not sure the suggested excerpt is very good. It doesn't say anything about what those algorithms are used for/what they do (and for me, English not being my first language, it's not clear at all what it refers to). (And it's missing a capital.)

Comment: I've just updated the wiki (I'm somewhat responsible as I was the first to approve the edit)